# MySQL How to update with MIN

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table with a minimum date vale from another table.

I have tried:

```
UPDATE `profiles` AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(attendance_data.Logdate) min_date 
FROM attendance_data) t2 ON t1.user_id=T2.user_id 
SET t1.first_scan_date=t2.min_date
```

And get Unknown column 't2.user_id' in 'on clause'

and also

```
UPDATE `profiles`  t1 
SET first_scan_date = (SELECT MIN(t2.Logdate) 
FROM attendance_data t2 
WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Any advice?

Comment: Are you trying to get the minimum `Logdate` for each user in the inner query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `profiles` AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, MIN(attendance_data.Logdate) min_date 
FROM attendance_data 
group by user_id) t2 ON t1.user_id=T2.user_id 
SET t1.first_scan_date=t2.min_date
```

Note that the right-hand side expression of inner join will return the minimum value of `logdate` for the particular `user_id`, and not the overall minimum.

If you just want to set all values in `profiles` to the minimum date, try this:

```
UPDATE `profiles` AS t1    
SET t1.first_scan_date= (SELECT MIN(attendance_data.Logdate) min_date FROM attendance_data)
```

Comment: @user3505581 Glad to help. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped resolve the issue.